# Why aren't those images similar according to Mathematica?

Tags: image-processing

I have two images:

[image]
[image]

They are extremely similar, however when I apply:

```
ImageDistance[im1, im2]
```

I get: 10.1867

For me it should be much lower

Comment: What’s the scale in question? What do more dissimilar images give? A single raw number is meaningless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to measure the distance between images. For example, for your two images the EarthMoversDistance seems to do a nice job.

```
im1 = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XoIB.jpg"];
im2 = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VmBF.jpg"];
ImageDistance[im1, im2, DistanceFunction -> "EarthMoverDistance"]
0.00580357
```

On the help page for ImageDistance (under Details and Options) there is quite a long list of various standard distance measures. Plus you have the option of defining your own.

Comment: I think EarthMoverDistance only compares the histograms